# Formula for giving the sum of a random percentage of an assigned value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope I can articulate this properly, I'll certainly try my best!

I would like to calculate a value based on a random percentage between 10 and 15% of a value I enter into the formula.

In pseudo-code this would be:

=sum(RandomPercentageBetween 10,15)555

where 555 is the value I want the random percentage of.

Lets imagine that random percentage is 9% in this instance.  The value returned by the formula would be 9% of 555 = 49.95

Can anyone help me with an actual formula if possible?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula `=RANDBETWEEN(10,15)/100*555`

> [RANDBETWEEN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4cc7f0d1-87dc-4eb7-987f-a469ab381685)
>
> Returns a random integer number between the numbers you specify. A new
>   random integer number is returned every time the worksheet is
>   calculated.
>
> RANDBETWEEN(bottom, top)
>
> - **Bottom**    Required. The smallest integer RANDBETWEEN will return.
> - **Top**    Required. The largest integer RANDBETWEEN will return.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted, if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Note that
the `RANDBETWEEN` function in Microsoft Excel
returns a random **integer** number,
so an expression like

```
=RANDBETWEEN(10,15)
```

will give only `5` possible values, `10,11,12,13,14,15`.

If you need a real random value between `10` and `15`, you can instead use

```
=(10+RAND()*(15-10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the formula:

```
=555*RANDBETWEEN(10,15)/100
```